# C shared memory with shmget-shmat not working like expected

Tags: c, linux

I found this strange behaviour when shearing memory between two processes

code 1

```
int main() {


    int *p;
    int shmID=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0666|IPC_CREAT);
    p=shmat(shmID,NULL,0);
    *p=0;
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0)
        wait(NULL);

    
    *p=*p+1;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
return 0;

}
```

output 1

```
1
2
```

like expected

code 2

```
int main() {


    int *p;
    int shmID=shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(int),0666|IPC_CREAT);
    p=shmat(shmID,NULL,0);
    *p=0;
    int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0)
        wait(NULL);

    *p=0;
    *p=*p+1;
    printf("%d\n",*p);
return 0;

}
```

output 2

```
1
1
```

When I give the sheared variable a value `*p=0` then it beheves like it is not sheared between the processes.

Comment: One major problem (in *both* examples) is that there's a data-race. The reading from memory, increment, writing back to the memory and the printing isn't atomic.The behavior of both programs will be *undefined*.

Comment: With that said, what probably happens in the second example is that one process runs to completion, writing zero to the memory, incrementing it to one, and printing that one. Then the other process runs to completion, doing the exact same thing: writing zero, incrementing it to one, and then printing that one.

Comment: I changed the code and added ` int pid=fork();
    if(pid>0)
        wait(NULL);` but nothing changed

Comment: That doesn't change the "run to completion" behavior. That will lett the child-process run to completion, before doing the exact same thing as the child process (setting memory to zero, incrementing to one, printing the one).

Comment: Yes you are right...thanks

Comment: IPC_PRIVATE creates a new shared memory segment. Each process creates a new shared memory segment. The other process does not know about it. Look at ftok function and see if you can use a key for referring to the same shared memory segment in the two processes.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an assumption about the behavior of `fork` here. You're assuming that after the `fork` call both processes will run truly concurrently.

In addition to the inherent race condition in your code, that assumption may not hold and really depends on the implementation. It may be that the initial process continues until blocked, and only then the `fork`ed process runs, which would explain the results in #2 and also why you didn't actually run into the race condition in your experiments.

Comment: Doesn't the `wait()` call ensure sequential access?  Oh, I see from the comments that the `fork()`/`wait()` code was added after you answered.  Never mind!